# Confused about SWI Prolog compiler warnings

Tags: compiler-warnings, swi-prolog

[image: Screenshot from SWIPL]

So I have two errors which do not make sense to me as of now. The first one being the `use :- dynamic Name/Arity` warning and the other one being the second two warnings below. Can anyone elaborate these for me?

Many thanks!

Comment: The suggestion for using a `dynamic` declaration is conditional:  **If** these are defined at runtime using assert/1. That means, only then ... The other errors tells you that something went wrong in the first clause of `find_identify/3`.  Evidently `find_link/4` and `chart_map/2` are not defined. You somehow added or omitted extra arguments. Or misspelled it

Comment: I will accept this as an answer if you make it one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by the user `false`:

The suggestion for using a `dynamic` declaration is conditional: If these are defined at runtime using `assert/1`. That means, only then ... The other errors tells you that something went wrong in the first clause of `find_identify/3`. Evidently `find_link/4` and `chart_map/2` are not defined. You somehow added or omitted extra arguments. Or misspelled it.